# scope method in AngularJS directive is not a function, when unit testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I have this Mocha test:

```
'use strict';

///////////////////////////////////

describe('all admin page directives', function () {

  let scope, $compile, element, tmp;
  beforeEach(module('app'));
  beforeEach(module('templates'));

  afterEach(function () {
    scope.$destroy();
  });

  describe('category', function () {

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
      $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
      var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      scope.rightSidebarData = {};
      $compile('<create-category right-sidebar-data="rightSidebarData"></create-category>')(scope);
      return scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should do something', function () {
       scope.updateModel();           //     <<<<<<  ERROR HERE
    });


  });

});
```

here is my directive:

```
/* globals angular */

angular.module('app').directive('createCategory',

  ['UserService', 'AssignmentService', 'NotificationService', 'USER', 'UserInfoService', 'AlertService', '$window',

    function (UserService, AssignmentService, NotificationService, USER, UserInfoService, AlertService, $window) {

      return {

        scope: {
          rightSidebarData: '=',
        },

        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: "pages/admin/views/templates/category/create-category.html",

        link: function ($scope, el, attrs) {

          $scope.rightSidebarData.setOrReset = function () {
            $scope.setOrReset();
          };

        },

        controller: function ($scope, FUNCTIONAL_TEAM_ENUM, CATEGORY_ENUM, CategoryService) {

          const rsd = $scope.rsd = $scope.rightSidebarData;

          $scope.setOrReset = function () {...};

          $scope.updateModel = function () {...};

          $scope.saveModel = function () {...};

        },
      };
    }
  ]);
```

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: scope.updateModel is not a function

Does anyone know what I need to do in my test to fix this?
Also, how do I know if I need to use `$rootScope.$new()` or if I should be passing the parent controller's scope?

Comment: The $compile service creates a new isolate scope for the `create-category` directive. So the `updateModel` function is attached to that child scope; not the root scope.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, how do I access the child scope? something like `getIsolateScope()` right?

Comment: See [angular.element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Comment: ehh, can't figure it out - I have `el =$compile(...)`, but the `scope()` and `isolateScope()` on that `el` don't have the `updateModel()` method.

Comment: @georgeawg if you can give me an answer I guarantee some upvotes

Comment: The [PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/6Fg4wM1q2iBi0nFSNH83?p=preview) was able to execute the function.

Comment: thanks, trying to figure it out, appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add another preprocessor in my karma config file:

```
preprocessors: {
  './public/pages/**/views/**/*.html':['ng-html2js'], // this
},
```

and then using the following, it worked:

```
'use strict';    
describe('all admin page directives', function () {

  let scope, el, tmp, isoScope;

  beforeEach(module('app'));
  beforeEach(module('ngMockE2E'));
  beforeEach(module('templates'));

  afterEach(function () {
    scope.$destroy();
  });

  describe('category', function () {

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
      const $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
      const $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      const $templateCache = $injector.get('$templateCache');
      console.log('create category template =>', $templateCache.get('pages/admin/views/templates/category/create-category.html'));

      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      scope.rightSidebarData = {};
      scope.rightSidebarData.model = {};
      let element = angular.element(`<create-category right-sidebar-data="rightSidebarData"></create-category>`);
      el = $compile(element)(scope);
      $rootScope.$digest();
      scope.$digest();
      el.isolateScope().setOrReset();
    }));

    it('should do something', function () {
      el.isolateScope().updateModel();
    });

  });

});
```